# Can I use 1/4 inch OSB on top of hardwood floor?

Tags: flooring

I have old four wide hardwood flooring with gaps , squeaks etc. Would like to lay down OSB then carpeting. What do I use to fasten OSB down?

Comment: The question in your title isn't the same as the question in the body. Please [edit] to make them consistent, define what "four wide hardwood flooring" is, and provide as much detail about what you're trying to do and _why_ as possible. Remember, we only know what you tell us - the more we know, the better we can help you. Then take the [tour] to get a better idea of how we work a bit differently here.

Comment: Your question presupposes that such a layer will do something for you. It probably won't. What problem are you trying to solve? See also [XY questions](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: _Can_ you put OSB over hardwood flooring? Sure! What's that going to accomplish for you? What would you use to fasten it? Nails, screws, glue, all of the above, whatever floats your goat.

Comment: Gravity works. Unless the gaps are more than 1/2" wide, carpet pad and no OSB works, too.

Comment: The one time I did something like this, it was in a historic shipyard building where they wanted to preserve the original boards despite the building still being under heavy use, and considered a few holes anchoring a plywood layer less damage than continuing to put wear on the floorboards. If that isn't your goal, I'm not sure what, if anything, the osb will do for you besides stealing a bit of ceiling height